# Strange Korean Characters in App Keywords Section

Tags: finder, applications, ventura

I just discovered some Korean-looking characters in the *Keywords* section of some apps (folder `/Applications` in macOS Ventura).

Below is an example of Safari when viewed in column view in Finder (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>), but I can see the same in the gallery view (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>). These "keywords" mostly come in repeated pairs. For Safari it's: ᄉᄑᄅ,ㅅㅍㄹ

[image: Screenshot of Safari information in column view with Korean characters in the Keywords section]

For the stock apps in the Applications folder supplied with Ventura the keywords are:

- Books: ᄃᄉ,ㄷㅅ
- Calculator: ᄀᄉᄀ,ㄱㅅㄱ
- Chess: ᄎᄉ,ㅊㅅ
- Clock: ㅅㄱ,ᄉᄀ
- Dictionary: ᄉᄌ,ㅅㅈ
- FaceTime: ᄑᄋᄉᄐᄋ,ㅍㅇㅅㅌㅇ
- Find My: ᄂᄋᄎᄀ,ㄴㅇㅊㄱ
- Font Book: ᄉᄎᄀᄅᄌ,ㅅㅊㄱㄹㅈ
- Home: ᄒ,ㅎ
- Image Capture: ᄋᄆᄌᄏᄎ,ㅇㅁㅈㅋㅊ
- Keynote: ᄏᄂᄐ,ㄱㅈ,ᄀᄌ,ㅋㄴㅌ
- Mail: ᄌᄌᄋᄑ,ㅇㅍ,ᄆᄋ,ᄋᄑ,ㅁㅇ,ㅈㅈㅇㅍ
- Maps: ㅈㄷ,ᄌᄃ
- News: ᄂᄉ,ㄴㅅ
- Notes: ᄆᄆ,ㅁㅁ,ㄴㅌ,ᄂᄐ
- Photo Booth: ㅍㅌㅂㅅ,ᄑᄐᄇᄉ
- Photos: ᄉᄌ,ㅅㅈ
- Preview: ㅁㄹㅂㄱ,ᄆᄅᄇᄀ
- Reminders: ᄆᄅᄋᄅ,ㅁㄹㅇㄹ
- Safari: ᄉᄑᄅ,ㅅㅍㄹ
- Shortcuts: ᄃᄎᄋ,ㄷㅊㅇ
- Stickies: ᄉᄐᄏ,ㅅㅌㅋ
- Stocks: ᄌᄉ,ㅈㅅ
- TextEdit: ㅌㅅㅌㅍㅈㄱ,ᄐᄉᄐᄑᄌᄀ
- Voice Memos: ᄋᄉᄆᄆ,ㅇㅅㅁㅁ
- Weather: ㄴㅆ,ᄂᄊ

Some are not even unique, e.g. Dictionary, Photos, and Stock have the same characters. If I type "ㅈㅅ" into Spotlight they all get found, plus a few others.

For comparison, the keywords for the Music app are:
Music, Radio, Apple Music, Apple Radio, iTunes Radio, Beats 1, Beats One, B1, Cloud Music Library, Apple Music Connect, My Music, iTunes

Running them through Google Translate (my Korean is not up-to-scratch), they don't seem to make any sense. Why are they there, and what do they mean?

Based on the comments that the keywords get added from the `info.plist` in the app bundle, I took a look at the *Migration Assistant* app, which does have English keywords. It however appears that there is a slight difference in spelling, which makes me wonder if those keywords really come from the `info.plist`.

The keywords as they appear in Finder for *Migration Assistant* (note the spelling of "Set up"):

[image: Screenshot of Migration Assistant information in column view with Korean characters in the Keywords section]

The keywords as they appear in the `info.plist` of the *Migration Assistant* app (note the spelling of "Setup"):

[image: Screenshot of the info.plist file for Migration Assistant in column view]

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, apart from it's a bug, but also note that usually the keywords get added to the info.plist in the app bundle (and those applications still show the right keywords), while these get theirs from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the info.plist for Safari but there was no keywords section at all. One for which proper keywords were shown is the Migration Assistant. The keywords shown are "Migrate, Transfer, Set up, Restore". The keywords under the MDItemKeywords key of info.plist strangely shows a different spelling for "Set up". It literally says: "Migrate, Transfer, Setup, Restore"

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the different spelling you mentioned.  "Setup" is shown under both, "Keywords" and "MDItemKeywords" on a Ventura and a Big Sur installation here.

Comment: I added an edit to the question with some images to show where I see those differences.

Comment: Thanks.  The keywords really do come from the info.plist (I've tested it), but maybe there are more places, which can override it.  Hopefully somebody knows where, or how and answers your question.